# Will running a wire from a PSU screw to my metal window sill do anything?

Tags: electrical, grounding

I recently moved into an old apartment with no ground in the wiring. An electrician checked, and it needs to be retrofitted for ground. This requires approval. In the meantime, I need my work station at home because I work at home, but it does zap me if I touch the back (the top of the case is fine) while it's plugged in. I also get zapped from the keyboard occasionally (only the left side, for whatever reason) and there's 54v in my speaker knob, even though the speaker's plug is only 2 prong. I assume it's coming from my computer.

While I wait for approval, my father in law (also an electrician) suggested that I run a wire from a screw on my computer's power supply casing to the nearby metal window sill as a temporary fix. This sounds extremely suspect to me. Would this really do anything?

Comment: So you don't trust info from an electrician, but want info from the web?

Comment: I doubt it unless the window is somehow attached to ground.  Running the ground wire out the window and pushing deep in the ground would be better.  Adding a GFCI outlet might help more if there is a ground fault.

Comment: @crip659 is there a possibility of this doing damage to anything, or is this worth a shot with the likelihood in mind that it won't help?

Comment: Unless the window gets hit by lighting or a power wire, quite low/almost zero possibility.

Comment: Your father-in-law is working off the assumption that the metal in a commercial building, ( apartment) is grounded.  Attaching a ground wire from computer case to the windowsill will alleviate the "zapping" issues your have. That is until you get a more permanent solution.

Answer (score 0):

On older houses with no ground. I usually suggest that to run you computer systems through a small UPS. This fixes a lot of errors. It cleans you power up. It creates a reference to ground on the load side. It prevents surges and sages from you power supply. And it also provides back up power for your electronics. I think it is still important to solve you supply side grounding problem, but the UPS will help sleep a little better at night.
Make sure you select a power supply large enough to handle the electronics you want to protect.
Hope this help and good luck.

Comment: The neutral side of a UPS likely is also connected to the mains neutral. That provides *no* isolation from the line; you'd still get zapped if the apparatus is ungrounded.

Comment: There are several types of UPS systems. The inexpensive ones will not help as they pass-through the line power. The more expensive ones would probably detect a line fault and go online running down the battery and not be able to recharge.